# Bazel cache over ssl

Tags: ssl, caching, bazel

Hej, Im trying to setup a bazel cache for my CI enviroment and so far all is working with no ssl, but when I enable nginx ssl with my fancy self signed certificate everything explodes...

Im using on .bazelrc:

```
build:remote --spawn_strategy=remote
build:remote --remote_local_fallback
build:remote --genrule_strategy=sandboxed
build:remote --remote_rest_cache=https://localhost:443
```

You are guessing right when I test with nginx with NO SSL I use:

```
build:remote --remote_rest_cache=http://localhost:80
```

The SSL side of life is not really working. I tried to browse around the answer in the documentation and on the irc channel but no luck so hope someone can give me an straight answer about how to use a ssl && remote cache on bazel...

Thanks!

Comment: Is the server's certificate trusted by your development machine for the given hostname? i.e. if you type `curl https://localhost:443`, will it connect to the server successfully? If not, you would have to either disable TLS certificate validation, or add that self-signed certificate to the list of trusted certificates... However, if you are on localhost, I am not sure what added value there is to using a HTTPS server, given that all data will stay on the machine itself.

Comment: not really the kind of answer i was expecting...

Comment: The issue that you have is very simple - your server has a self-signed TLS certificate, which is recognized by most software as invalid. You have the following solutions: disable certificate validation, add the current certificate to the list of accepted certificates, or obtain a certificate that will be accepted by all clients. Note that, if the cache is only for the localhost bazel instances, HTTPS does not bring any added value.

Comment: at the end of the day the solution was on adding the keys on the truststore bazel uses.